# How to reach BSL airport from Freiburg by mid-morning?

Tags: airport-transfer, transportation

I'd like to reach the BSL airport by 8:30 on a Sunday morning, sleeping in Freiburg, Germany.

I'm a bit confused on what my options are.

Apparently there's a train from Freiburg to Basel arriving at 7:20, but I have no clue if that would be reliable, and how to reach the airport, considering that apparently it's actually located in the French town of Mulhouse, unless I have misunderstood something.

Or I could just get a cab, but unless I'm mistaken they are about 150-200€, which is a bit higher than what I was hoping to spend. This could be split, but I wouldn't know how.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can take any train to Basel SBB and from there bus line 50. The bus ride is just 16 minutes. Technically, the airport is located in France, but practically it's just in the outskirts of Basel.

You can use the web page of Deutsche Bahn (bahn.de) to get all the relevant connections, using "Freiburg(Breisgau) Hbf" and "Basel EuroAirport" as destination. E.g. there is a train leaving at 07:04, with a bus arriving at 08:30 - the connection times are rather short, but the bus runs every 10 minutes, so this shouldn't be a problem in case you miss it.

If you buy the ticket, make sure which parts of the trip are included and which are not. On the first glance it looks like the bus is included in the price, but it might be it is not. The destination listed in the upper part of the ticket is what counts, the itinerary below is just for your information.

Comment: If you take the train + bus option, be aware that there are two train stations in Basel. The one you want is Basel SBB, not Basel Bad. Bahnhof (the "German" station).

Comment: @jcaron The bus leaves from Basel SBB, but you have more connections available if you accept to change at Basel Badischer Bahnhof to a tram to Basel SBB. (One or the other option might be significantly cheaper, depending on which fares are still available from DB)

Answer (score 3):

There's also a direct bus from Freiburg-am-Breisgau to the EuroAirport:

https://www.freiburger-reisedienst.de/FreiburgerReisedienst/fahrplan.php

On Sunday mornings you have a bus leaving at 6:45 arriving at 7:40. The cost is 22.99 €.

The same bus is apparently also sold via Flixbus, at the same price:

https://shop.global.flixbus.com/search?departureCity=92&arrivalCity=8148&route=Freiburg+%28i.Br.%29-Basel+EuroAirport&rideDate=26.08.2018&adult=1&_locale=en